# How did an LED go from being a point source of light to an extended source?

Tags: led, light, damage, lighting

A night light with an LED under a dome screen projected a sharp image initially, but a blurry image after the first night. The screen appeared to be undamaged, this led me to believe that the LED started out as a point source and after some time (more than 2 minutes, but less than 12 hours) the light-emitting area spread out. I'm curious what the physical process behind this phenomenon is.

The LED looks to be ~1mm square, the whole area seems to light up. I don't have one that is still a point source – we ordered a few more as cheap gifts, but the others all arrived blurry out of the box.

From my rudimentary knowledge of diodes, I imagine the entire junction should either be allowing current to pass, or none of it. If an imperfection creates a zone that becomes conductive first, the current should spread over the whole junction quickly... should it? Or if part of the junction starts out as more conductive, there would be a huge change in brightness as LEDs "break in" from equalizing... wouldn't there?

Is there some alternative explanation that I didn't think of?

Comment: Based upon a sample size of 1!

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all, but: While the entire diode *allows* current to flow it will prefer to flow on the path of least-resistance directly between the electrodes.  However the high-resistance p-type side of an LED will typically be covered by a transparent (ITO) conductor to ensure that the current really does go through the entire area of the junction.